# How to apply a function to each row of dataset that I imported to Mathematica and get the result of each row

Tags: functions, row, wolfram-data-framework

I wrote a function that uses Monte Carlo Simulation using flipping a coin to calculate the value of the call option in Mathematica. I want to apply the function to 63 rows of my dataset that contain the real data. In other words, I want the function uses the values of each row for its variables I can put values for variables of the function, but it takes time to do that for a large number of data

```
ClearAll[S, M, K, k, \[CurlyEpsilon], n, H, T, \[CapitalDelta]t]
Array[S, {365, 1000}]
Array[M, 1000]
For[k = 1, k < 1001, k++, 
 S[1, k] = S0; \[Mu] = 0.0168; \[CapitalDelta]t = T/n; T = 1/365;
 n = 365; \[Sigma] = sigma;
 For[n = 1, n < 365, n++, \[CurlyEpsilon] = 2 RandomInteger[] - 1;
  S[n + 1, k] = 135.95
   Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]t] \[CurlyEpsilon] \[Sigma] S[n, 
      k] + \[CapitalDelta]t \[Mu] S[n, k] + \[CapitalDelta]t \[Mu] S[
      n, k] + S[n, k]]; M[k] = S[365, k]]
Array[P, 1000]
P[1] = 0
For[k = 1, k < 1001, k++, 
 P[k + 1] = 
  P[k] + 1/((1 + \[Mu]*T/(365*365))^365)*1/1000*Max[M[k] - 140, 0]
 ]
Print[P[1000]]
```

The values that I want to use frequently are:
K as my strike price(here is 140)

S0 as my price of stock here( S[1, k]= 135.95

tau as my time to maturity here as (T=1/365)

sigma as my volatility here as (sigma)

r as my risk-free rate here as([Mu=0.0168])

this is the data I want to use:

```
tau            r     sigma     S0     K
0.00273973  0.0168  0.2564  135.59  140
0.00547945  0.016   0.3546  134.56  140
0.00821918  0.0165  0.2227  134.41  140
0.0109589   0.0154  0.225   134.22  140
0.0136986   0.0152  0.2043  134.13  140
0.0219178   0.0156  0.1747  134.21  140
0.0246575   0.0175  0.1626  135.32  140
0.0273973   0.0159  0.1717  133.76  140
0.0328767   0.0176  0.1659  133.91  140
0.0410959   0.0177  0.1599  133.92  140
0.0410959   0.0167  0.1472  133.22  140
0.0438356   0.0154  0.1628  131.91  140
0.0465753   0.0176  0.1625  131.99  140
0.0493151   0.0176  0.1701  132.12  140
0.0520548   0.0176  0.1628  132.91  140
0.060274    0.0178  0.1449  134.45  140
0.0657534   0.018   0.1421  133.77  140
0.0684932   0.0177  0.1387  135.09  140
0.0712329   0.0179  0.1423  135.97  140
0.0794521   0.018   0.1442  134.34  140
0.0821918   0.0185  0.1553  133.84  140
0.0849315   0.0177  0.1561  133.2   140
0.0876712   0.0178  0.1487  134.52  140
0.090411    0.0184  0.1452  134.31  140
0.0986301   0.0169  0.1422  134.4   140
0.10137 0.0173  0.1508  134 140
0.10411 0.0192  0.1548  134.48  140
0.106849    0.0182  0.1501  135.59  140
0.109589    0.0184  0.151   135.47  140
0.117808    0.0178  0.1548  137.61  140
0.120548    0.0183  0.1567  137.69  140
0.123288    0.0177  0.1174  138.78  140
0.126027    0.0177  0.1284  137.89  140
0.128767    0.0174  0.1281  137.67  140
0.136986    0.0192  0.1308  135.53  140
0.139726    0.0181  0.1411  133.73  140
0.142466    0.0181  0.1365  135.25  140
0.145205    0.0194  0.142   133.82  140
0.147945    0.0176  0.1315  135.97  140
0.156164    0.0177  0.133   135.44  140
0.158904    0.0193  0.1336  134.07  140
0.161644    0.0179  0.1414  134.38  140
0.164384    0.0188  0.1423  133.96  140
0.167123    0.0186  0.1411  132.58  140
0.175342    0.0177  0.1446  134.09  140
0.178082    0.0173  0.1377  134.26  140
0.180822    0.018   0.2 142.11  140
0.183562    0.0179  0.1975  143 140
0.186301    0.0184  0.2036  142.04  140
0.194521    0.019   0.208   142.76  140
0.19726 0.0183  0.219   141.13  140
0.2 0.0177  0.2242  139.67  140
0.20274 0.0172  0.2336  138.38  140
0.205479    0.0185  0.2188  141.28  140
0.213699    0.0192  0.2182  142.99  140
0.216438    0.0189  0.2313  142.02  140
0.219178    0.0189  0.2402  141.69  140
0.221918    0.0192  0.2246  143.66  140
0.224658    0.0192  0.2186  145.42  140
0.232877    0.0192  0.2214  143.24  140
0.235616    0.0192  0.2117  143.55  140
0.238356    0.0192  0.2108  143.16  140
0.241096    0.0182  0.2138  141.68  140
```

Comment: Don't use the word "dataset" as it has a pre-assigned meaning in Mathematica. Also I would say "real data" implies that there are some complex values as well in the picture which is not true in your case. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say this is the mock function with five parameters:

```
f[τ_, r_, σ_, S0_, k_] := r + τ
```

Store data in a text file (say "test.txt" and set the folder accordingly); i.e., copy paste your data in a text file; name and save it in an accessible folder.

Next, import it as a list of values because we need rows containing five parameters each as a list.

```
rawdata = Import["C:/test.txt", "Table"]
title = First@rawdata;
data = Rest@rawdata;
```

Apply the function to each row:

```
f @@@ data
```

Now you will have to write the function.